# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've been working on a project and I wan't trying to figure out how to make the `UNION` Mysql method in Codeigniter 3, I can't find what problem I have, here's the model file that I've created, can some one help:

```
class Reference_model extends CI_Model {
function  search($term,$orig){
    //Affichage des produits par référence
    $this->db->select('*')
        ->distinct()
        ->from('tReference')
        ->like('sReference',$term)
        ->or_like('nReference', $term)
        ->or_like('sSearch', $term)
        ->or_like('sSort', $term)
        ->get();
    $q1 = $this->db->last_query();
    if (isset($orig)) {
    $this->db->select('nManufacturer')
        ->distinct()
        ->from('tManufacturer')
        ->where_in('nManufacturer=tReference.nManufacturer')
        ->get();
    $q2 =  $this->db->last_query();
    }else {
    $q2='';
    }

    $query = $this->db->query($q1." UNION ".$q2);
    $ret = array();
    $ret['rows'] = $query->result();
    $ret['number'] = $query->num_rows();

    return $ret;
}
}
```

And thank you all for your help

Comment: Oh my god ! Error occured ! ?? Can you see `Related Questions` answered at Bottom Right corner?

Comment: Can you find any solution that is relevant to my problem, in those solution that you are talking about?

Comment: WHat is `->where_in('nManufacturer=tReference.nManufacturer')`? You sure it is right way? Add the full error.

Comment: First print Raw SQL Query what is getting executed in CI. Then execute it in phpmyadmin and see where is the error. This is very simple.

Comment: there's no solution till now!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get `UNION` of two query then there is a requirements that names of columns (which are being selected) should be same..

In your case , in 1st query `select('*')` and in 2nd `select('nManufacturer')` and i am sure, these 2 queries are selecting different columns.